# Why Marshal.GetLastWin32Error after calling CallNtPowerInformation always returns 0?

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I'm trying to get `SystemBatteryState` using `CallNtPowerInformation`. I set `SetLastError` attribute to `true`, but `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()` always returns 0, even when status code returned by `CallNtPowerInformation` not equals to 0.

Example of code where I'm expecting to `GetLastWin32Error` return non-zero value (I allocate for outputBuffer less memory than needed):

```
var outputBufferLength = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SYSTEM_BATTERY_STATE)) - 1;
var outputBuffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(outputBufferLength);

var statusCode = CallNtPowerInformation(
    POWER_INFORMATION_LEVEL.SystemBatteryState,
    IntPtr.Zero,
    0,
    outputBuffer,
    (uint)outputBufferLength
);

var errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
Console.WriteLine("Win32 error code: " + errorCode);
```

My `CallNtPowerInformation`:

```
[DllImport("powrprof.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true,
            CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern uint CallNtPowerInformation(
    [In] POWER_INFORMATION_LEVEL informationLevel,
    [In] IntPtr inputBuffer,
    [In] uint inputBufferLength,
    [Out] IntPtr outputBuffer,
    [In] uint outputBufferLength
);
```

`CallNtPowerInformation` returns code 3221225507 (STATUS_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL), but `GetLastWin32Error` returns 0. Should it at all return some error? Or what am I doing wrong?

P.S. Maybe it's enough to have only status code from `CallNtPowerInformation`, but why do we need then `SetLastError = true`?

Comment: NtPowerInformation is a [kernel function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-ntpowerinformation), usable only by device drivers.  Some unnamed Microsoft programmer took a short-cut a long time ago, making it accessible to user programs as well.  Without making it a formal winapi function that interprets the error returns, tsk, tsk, tsk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetLastWin32Error` will only work for methods where the documentation says that they set the last error value. `CallNtPowerInformation` is [not one of those](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/powerbase/nf-powerbase-callntpowerinformation). This method directly returns an error code, so the last error code will not be updated. Using `SetLastError = true` in the declaration of a method that does not use the last error value is useless and has no effect (other than eventually returning the error code from a previous failed system call).

The documentation explicitly says something like "Use GetLastError to get more information" for functions that update the value returned by GetLastError.

Comment: Thanks! I saw a lot of examples of using `CallNtPowerInformation` and there was `SetLastError = true` set so I thought it makes some sense.