# Setting primary group in c# on Linux

Tags: c#, .net, linux, .net-core, libc

In Linux, I am logged in as bj:bj as non root user:group.

```
bj@pc-bj:~$ id
uid=1000(bj) gid=1000(bj) groups=1000(bj),5(tty),20(dialout),24(cdrom),25(floppy),29(audio),1006(internetallowed)
```

I want to **temporary** change my primary group to another group "internetallowed" to which I belong. In bash I can do this successfully by the newgrp command:

```
bj@pc-bj:~$ newgrp internetallowed
bj@pc-bj:~$ id
uid=1000(bj) gid=1006(internetallowed) groups=1006(internetallowed),5(tty),20(dialout),24(cdrom),25(floppy),29(audio),1000(bj)
```

Now I want to do this also in C# / DotNet 7.0. I've found out that newgrp uses the setgid() function from libc. So I tried this:

```
public static class LinuxAPI
{
    [DllImport ("libc", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int setgid (UInt32 gid);
    public static int GetLastError()
    {
        return Marshal.GetLastSystemError();
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var result = LinuxAPI.setgid(1006);  // returns -1 (error)
    var error = LinuxAPI.GetLastError();  // returns 1 (Operation not permitted)
}
```

setgid() fails with errno 1 (Operation not permitted).
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
public static int GetLastError()
{
    return Marshal.GetLastSystemError();
}
```

with

```
public static int GetLastError()
{
     return Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
}
```

Comment: On Linux systems GetLastSystemError() should be used, according to the .net manuals. Even if i use GetLastWin32Error this won't fix the error.

Comment: Which version of the .net framework are you using?

Comment: using .NET 7.0.403

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70479269/why-marshal-getlastwin32error-after-calling-callntpowerinformation-always-return See if this helps any

Comment: My issue is not with GetLastError. The function setgid() fails as it returns -1. GetLastError is just to have a clue.

Comment: On my system setgid(1000) returns 0

Comment: Probably because your primary group is already 1000. Try another group to which that user belong....